# The problem with the IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request and the organizer in Outlook

Tags: outlook, mapi

Outlook displays the following text: “As the meeting organizer, you do not need to respond to the meeting,” and this happens when Outlook opens my IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request message.
The message store owner is not the organizer, and I really don't know why Outlook can display this text. Can you help me find out the reason for the behavior of Outlook?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes, I found that Outlook requires PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME or/and PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS properties. We used IConverterSession to convert a meeting request from a raw MIME. But Outlook didn't fill these properties.

Answer (score 0):

If the user/account from which the meeting request was sent has the same `display name` as the invited attendee then Outlook thinks the meeting organizer is the same person as the attendee. In such cases, Outlook will not let you ACCEPT the meeting request, but instead shows:

`As the meeting organizer, you do not need to respond to the meeting.`

As a workaround, you need to ensure the display names are not exactly the same. Change one of the display names and the other, so they look different.